# Reverse ssh to Cloud server from Raspberry

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, ssh-tunnel

I have a use case where I have 6 of my raspberry pi sitting behind a private firewall and I need access to them from my local systems. So I came up with a architecture shown below

1. From my rpi reverse ssh to a specific port of my cloud server
2. And from my local system connect to the rpi's using my cloud server as a jumpbox (SSH ProxyJump)

   ```
                       Firewall
   +--------+              |    +---------+             +----------------+
   | Rpi 1  |-> 2101/tcp ->| -> |         | <- 22/tcp - | Local System 1 |
   +--------+              |    |         |             +----------------+
                           |    |         |
   +--------+              |    |  Cloud  |             +----------------+
   | Rpi 2  |-> 2201/tcp ->| -> | Server  | <- 22/tcp - | Local System 2 |
   +--------+              |    |         |             +----------------+
      ...                  |    |         |
   +--------+              |    |         |             +----------------+
   | Rpi 6  |-> 2601/tcp ->| -> |         | <- 22/tcp - | Local System 3 |
   +--------+              |    +---------+             +----------------+
   ```

Initially, I used direct SSH command's, but I ran into issues like, the connection becomes stale and unresponsive after a period of time. So, I moved to `autossh`. I started a `systemd` to do this operation.

```
autossh -Nf -M 0 -o ServerAliveInterval=120 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -R 2101:127.0.0.1:22 root@my-server-ip
```

This works fine, for my 6 devices. But when I try to connect more devices, The tunnel doesn't seem to be connecting(i.e) Tunnel established from rpi, but nothing on `netstat -lnpt` on the cloud server.

Now I need to know if this the right approach to solve this use case. Given that, this count of 6 rpi's can go upto 20 or 30 in future. Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" – What does it mean? `autossh` cannot connect? or it cannot establish a tunnel? or it allegedly can but the tunnel is not available later? or what? Assuming 7 devices, is it always the same one whose connection "doesn't seem to work"? What if they start in a different sequence? What if they use another set of ports? Can you impersonate a Rpi from a local system and try to establish yet another tunnel? What happens then? Have you considered VPN?

Comment: I use 7 rpi's for the connection (All on unique ports). I can see the autossh is running on all the rpi, but when i give `netstat -lnpt` on the cloud server, i see only the first 6 rpi's ports. The 7th is never listed even after shutting down one of the first 6.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Restarting the cloud server made the 7th rpi to work (One of the first 6 is still shutdown, so a total of 6 tunnels only). 
I am more interested to know if this is the best approach for this kind of a use case?

Comment: all your raspberry are in the same physical location ?

Comment: @EchoMike444, No. they are in different network.